# Using Apache HTTPD to proxy requests and when in error set status 200 and the error document

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I'm using Apache HTTPD 2.4.12 to proxy a request to a remote server. If the remote host returns an error code such as 502 then I need it to handle it and return a *custom* error page with a status of 200. This is a workaround for an application issue which doesn't handle non-200 errors well and needs a particular payload.

I can only get it to return the custom error page with status 502 (without RewriteRule) or a standard OK page with status set as 200. Here's part of my httpd.conf which replicates the latter:

```
<Location /dm>
   ProxyPass http://url.of/dm/
   ProxyPassReverse http://url.of/dm/
   ErrorDocument 502 /error/error.html
</Location>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /error/error.html    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /error/error.html [R=200,L]
```

Or are there better alternatives than Apache HTTPD for this? I'd really like to use Apache if possible because it's already installed on the system.

Answer (score 0):

I had mod_lua installed on our Apache instance so fixed this by setting in the httpd.conf:

```
<Files *.lua>
    SetHandler lua-script
</Files>

<Location /dm>
   ProxyPass http://url.of/dm/
   ProxyPassReverse http://url.of/dm/
   ErrorDocument 502 /error/error.lua 
</Location>
```

Then created the script /error/error.lua:

```
function handle(r)
    r.content_type = "text/html" -- set the output to text/html
    r:puts("My custom error payload")
    r.status = 200
    return apache2.OK
end
```